# Can every group be obtained from a choice of Sylow subgroup for every prime divisor?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The question is almost clear from title:

> If $G$ is a finite group of order $p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_r^{n_r}$ then is it always possible to choose one Sylow subgroup for every prime divisor of $|G|$  such that $G$ is (set theoretic) product of the chosen Sylow subgroups? (i.e. is $G$ equal to $P_{k_1}\cdots P_{k_r}$ where $\{k_1,\cdots,k_1\}=\{1,\cdots,2\}$).

Comment: What do you mean by "set-theoretic product"?  Any set of order $|G|$ is a direct product of sets of the right size, _as a set_, but it's certainly false if you want the product to be group-theoretic (Sylow subgroups are not always normal).

Comment: For subgroups $H,K$ we define set theoretic product $HK=\{hk\colon h\in H,k\in K\}$; generalize this to set theoretic product of finitely many subgroups. (The considerations are not so trivial as in your comment!)

Comment: @Yuan: I didn't see it; please see this link https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0ahUKEwjzxaC7wbDMAhUJC44KHR11CPAQFghYMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.warwick.ac.uk%2F~mareg%2Fdownload%2Fpapers%2Fsylowprod%2Fsylowprod.ps&usg=AFQjCNGXQoUTTZOIGos1B38YcvqUsGAwjQ&sig2=fUxVlJgiJ2xf0NvDKYH2Gw. It concerns same question, with positive answer if $G$ is solvable. But I didn't see counter-example if $G$ is not solvable.

Comment: Yuan: I saw the link in my previous comment carefully, and got the answer to my original question. Holt and Rowley have shown by an example that this is *not always* possible!.....(Almost close-up of question!!!)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The product of two Sylow subgroups internally will have the correct order, but it will not be a group in general, and so when we multiply three or more Sylow subgroups, the order may be less than expected.

Comment: @Slade: ah, you're right. My apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

${\rm PSU}(3,3)$ of order $6048$ is an example in which this is not possible. Holt and Rowley showed that this is the smallest simple example.